# ionic Native + geofance + iOS ERROR : "Location always permissions not granted"

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

please help me out from this error.

**ionic Native + geofance + iOS**

I am dealing with geofence with ionic native, with Android Geofence working fine, but iOS give me error **error : "Location always permissions not granted"**.

=========================================

this.geofence.initialize().then(data => {

```
      console.log('Geofence Plugin Ready');
         let fence = {
            id              : '69ca1b88-6fbe-4e80-a4d4-ff4d3748acdb', //any unique ID
            latitude        : 21.08328129405459, //
            longitude       : 72.88010023534298, //
            radius          : 30, 
            transitionType  : 3, 
            notification    : { //notification settings
                                id              :  11212,//
                                title           : 'Insta Place',
                                text            : 'You are Near the Location.',
                                icon            : 'file://icon.png',
                                openAppOnClick  : true
                            }
          }
          // alert(JSON.stringify(fence));

          this.geofence.addOrUpdate(fence).then(
             (data) => console.log('Geofence added'),
             (err) => alert('Geofence failed to add Please Turn On your device location and try again.'+ err)
           );
        },err => {
           alert('Geofence Plugin Not Ready' + JSON.stringify(err));
        })
```

============================

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for me the solution is the following privacy put in your **.plist** file.

NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription
    This app requires constant access to your location in order to track your position, even when the screen is off or the app is in the background.

thanks.